# play framework: how to repopulate form on validation-failure when using datamodel?

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework

I'm building some crude CMS-like functionality (to get acquinted with Play Framework). For this test-case I've build 2 pages, 1 for listing tags and 1 for creating/editing/saving tags.

The flow is like this (routes-file):

```
#list tags
GET /tags  Application.listTags 

#view/edit existing tag
GET /tag/{<(?!new$)(.+)>name} Application.showTag  

#new tag
GET /tag/new  Application.showTag
```

the create/view/edit page displays a form which gets it's values from a tagDTO. 
The normal flow works without problems, but when the form gives validation-errors (e.g: the tag-name must exist) I want to display the page again, repopulating the form with the edited values.

For this (following the Play Framework conventions) I could use the 'flash'-object which contains these last values, but the form is already bound to the tagDTO (which is null on redirect) instead of the 'flash'-object.

First the code: 
Application.java

```
.....

public static void showTag(String name) {
    TagDTO tagDTO = TagDTO.buildDTOFromModelOrNew(name);
    render(tagDTO); 
}


/**
 * Save tag and redirect to Show
 * 
 * @param name
 * @param displayname
 * @param isnew
 */
public static void saveTag(
        @Required(message="Name is required") String name,
        String displayname,
        boolean isnew) 
{
    checkAuthenticity();
    if(validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash(); 
        validation.keep(); 
        showTag(null);
    }

    //fetch tagDTO based on backend or create new if not exist
    TagDTO tag = TagDTO.buildDTOFromModelOrNew(name);

    // Append / Overwrite values
    tag.displayname = displayname;
    tag.name = name;

    //save result to model
    TagDTO.buildAndSaveModelFromDTO(tag);

    flash.success("Thanks for " + (isnew?"creating":"updating") + " tag " + tag.name);

    //redirect to show
    showTag(tag.name);
}
```

And ShowTag.html

```
    #{extends 'main.html' /}
    #{if flash.success}
        <p class="success">${flash.success}</p>
    #{/if}

    #{ifErrors}
        <p class="errors">Oops...</p>
    #{/ifErrors}

    #{form @Application.saveTag()}
        #{authenticityToken /}
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="${tagDTO.name}" />
            <span class="error">#{error 'name' /}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="displayname">Displayname: </label>
            <input type="text" name="displayname" id="displayname" value="${tagDTO.displayname}" />
            <span class="error">#{error 'displayname' /}</span> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="isnew" value="${tagDTO.isnew}" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit your comment" />
        </p>
    #{/form}
```

Now I could think of some ways to make it work, but none really elegant:

1. bind the form to the flash-object (or params-object) and populate the flas/params- object from the tagDTO
2. on validation-failure, refetch the tagDTO (not avail anymore so DB-call necessary) and overwrite values in tagDTO with values available in flash-object, bind form to tagDTO.
3. like 2, but using some sort of cache to quickly fetch tagDTO (so no need for db-call)
4. Some general  mechanism to (de)serialize tagDTO from/to the session.

In short, I don't like any of them really. 
What would you consider to be a best practice in this situation? Or is there any functionality in the Play Framework that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the explicit render calls comes handy. Retain the form values from previous submission and give it back (if validation fails) as follows,

```
checkAuthenticity();
if(validation.hasErrors()) {
    render("@showTag", name, displayname, isnew);
}
```

This will avoid the extra redirect (307 in case of Play!) that would have happened if you had called 'action from another action'.

Comment: good to know the explicit render-call construction (using the template of another action) . I changed your suggestion a bit, by repolulating my tagDTO and suppyling that, e. g:  render("@showTag", tagDTO);

Comment: also good to know (and pretty logical when you think of it) that you don't need params.flash(); and/or validation.keep(); before doing the render("@showTag", tagDTO); (if you do, you get screwed with the errors from the previous post). Thanks again

Comment: Anyone got a modern day solution for this in scala?

Answer (score 0):

Render the form again and avoid the redirect is a solution. I think it's OK if a user press F5 he will get the error again. But I think you should create a reload/cancel button, so the user can dismiss all the information.

To have always the correct URL you can do the following in the routes.conf:

```
GET  /tag/create     TagController.create
POST /tag/create     TagController.insert
```

The flash solution has the disadvantage that your cookie can get really big.

Comment: Thanks, I did in fact already alter the routes file to something similar. Just to be sure, you're in fact promoting the same solution as 'sjn' did above? (so render without redirect, and no use of the flash-object) ?