# Repopulating form fields in Play Framework

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, twirl

Using the [Play Framework (2.6) documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms); I am attempting to handle form submission. But I'm running into an issue in repopulating the form fields - which is what I want to do if it has errors (so users can edit their entry rather than having to re-enter).

```
   newForm.bindFromRequest.fold(

     errorForm => {
       BadRequest(views.html.form(errorForm))
     },
     formData => {
       val oWriteJso = Json.toJsObject(formData) match {
         case x if(x.fields.nonEmpty) => getCreatedFieldValues(x)
         case _ => None
       }
       val oRes = Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing("success" -> "Entry saved!")
       apiC.writeAndRedirect("c", collName, None, oWriteJso)(oRes)(request)

     }

   )
```

My issue is that the example in the documentation only shows how to pass `errorForm` directly to a form template (e.g. `views.html.form`) rather than being able to render the whole page again (i.e. using `views.html.index` or a `Redirect`) with the input form fields being populated from the previous request. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782016/play-framework-how-to-repopulate-form-on-validation-failure-when-using-datamode) as the closest to this issue but it is a little old and I am using `Scala` so wasn't able to implement it. Just have no idea how anyone else is doing this or what the sensible, standard approach is. Thanks for any light on this_

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Play helper functions for generating input tags in your view file. They should populate with your values from the last request.

For example you can create an HTML form in your view file using helper methods like this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.userPost()) {
  @helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("age"))
}
```

You can take a look at Play documentation about helpers in view files at the following link:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaForms#Showing-forms-in-a-view-template

Comment: Thanks but I can display the input form in the template (using helper methods) - passing the error form to a template which renders the whole page is trickier. You mention that "_They should populate with your values from the last request_" - not if calling an action such as `Redirect(routes.SspC.index)` - the `request` doesn't contain any of the form data. Anyway I think that I may have to send the `error form` to the template, convert it to HTML and then send it as an optional parameter to the main template

Comment: Actually `Html` cannot be sent to a route action so still stumped by this one!

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris Sorry, I think you can't display form data in your `BadRequest` part. If you redirect the user to another URL, you will lost the current values of form data. You should return an `Ok` response with form data like this:
`val anyData  = Map("username" -> "foo"); val formWithData = form.bind(anyData);  Ok(views.html.user.userLogin(formWithData))`